# Using a threshold image to change brightness values in an actual image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

**What i'm trying to do:**

1. Take an image
2. Apply a gaussian filter to the image
3. Equalise the image based on OpenCv equaliseHist function
4. From the equalised image take the thresholded image:

if in the thresholded image pixel is equal to black then in the actual image decrease the brightness of that pixel, if its white in the threshold image increase the brightness in the actual image

**Below is currently what code i have so far:**

```
img = cv2.imread('1.bmp')


img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

""" Take the image and slipt it into the HSV colour spectrem """

h,s,v= cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))

""" Equalise the histogram for the V value """

eq_V = cv2.equalizeHist(v)

""" Merge all the values back into one image """

eq_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.merge([h, s, eq_V]), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(eq_image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


[rows, columns, channels] = img.shape

blacks = np.zeros((rows,columns,channels))
whites = np.zeros((rows,columns,channels))



for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        if th1[row,column].all() == 0:
            """ Equalise the v value """
            blacks[row,column] = v[row,column]

        else:
            """ Equalise the v value """
            whites[row,column] = v[row,column]


addTogether = cv2.add(blacks,whites)


cv2.imshow("frame", addTogether.astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**My problem**

The part that i am struggling with is step 4. mentioned above. I am currently building an image based on whats black and whats white and then adding those images together to get back to my orginal image state.

What i seem to be unable to do/figure out is how to adjust the v value of the hsv for the image and then how to merge the whole image back together with the new v values alsongside the hue and saturation values.

**Image from a latest attempt**

[image]

Comment: @Sounak im using that line to say if the pixel in `th1` is black then i want to change the birghtness of that pixel(in that case, make it slightly darker) in the `eq_image` else if its white in `th1` then change the brightness of the pixel to be slightly brighter in `eq_image`

Comment: I think your `addTogether` is exactly same as `v`, but has 3 channels.

Comment: currently it is yes, as i am unsure on how to go about adjusting the `v` in the `black` and `white` numpy arrays

Comment: are you trying to increase or decrease by a constant value?

Comment: trying to do both, this is based on whether the pixel in question is black or white in the mask. If its black then decrease brightness, if white increase and yes currently it would be with a constant value

Comment: @Sounak your comment from yesterday seems to have disappeared im not sure why, i dont suppose you remember what it said?

Comment: you are using a binary threshold on a color image, are you sure you want to do that? maybe `cv2.inRange` would suite better? Also, have a look at functions like `cv2.bitwise_and` and `cv2.bitwise_not`. You should be able to modify pixel values in the source image using a mask without for loops.

Comment: using the binary threshold on the color image was a mistake, it should have just been on the `v` value. Ive tried this code but to no avail `th_up = cv2.bitwise_and(v,th1) + 5
th_down = cv2.bitwise_not(v,cv2.bitwise_not(v, th1)) - 5
result = th_up + th_down` 
Ill try and add the image thats given from that in the post

Comment: That's a wrong logic.

Comment: im not sure where ive gone wrong

Comment: `th_v_up = (cv2.bitwise_and(v, th1) + cv2.bitwise_and(np.ones(v.shape).astype(np.uint8) * 5, th1))` will increase the pixel values corresponding to the white pixels in `th1` by 5

Comment: ok ill try that and if i wanted to change the value of the pixels corresponding to black pixels in `th1` would i just change the `cv2.bitwise_and` to `cv2.bitwise_not`??

Comment: `th1_n = cv2.bitwise_not(th1)`
`th_v_down = (cv2.bitwise_and(v, th1_n) - cv2.bitwise_and(np.ones(v.shape).astype(np.uint8) * 5, th1_n))`

Comment: thanks a lot that seems to have done the trick, if you want to post it as an answer then ill happily mark it as the answer and upvote it

Comment: be careful when adding values to `uint8` images, if the sum becomes more than `255` it will be rounded to `orginal_pixel_value + added_value - 256` or the image might change it's `dtype` to `uint16`

Comment: would there be a way to avoid this from happening?